# How to get http headers when using HTTParty gem in Rails?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, httparty

I'm using **gem 'devise_token_auth'** **gem 'httparty'**.

After **post** action, I want to get the ff header from response:

**Example:**
    HTTParty.post("/auth/sign_in", @options)

**I need:**

```
access_token: response.headers['access-token'],
client: response.headers['client'],
expiry: response.headers['expiry'],
token_type: response.headers['token-type'],
uid: response.headers['uid']
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the headers HTTParty returns this way:

```
require 'httparty'

response = HTTParty.post("/auth/sign_in", @options)

puts response.headers
```

You can also see an example here: https://johnnunemaker.com/httparty/